# How to reset a label's text from a function

Tags: xcode, label, reset

I seem to be having problems updating a label from a function in the view controller. Sorry for the question, but I have looked at many similar and it seems like I am doing it correctly. Very inexperienced and sure I am missing something simple. I have checked that the IB@Outlet is set. Have tried with and without self in front of the label name. Have tried to assign redValueLabel.text with and without quotes and as a variable inside the quotes: "(labelvalue)". Below is the code and an error that shows everytime I run simulator (not sure relevant).

```
    @IBAction func reset(_ sender: AnyObject) {
               
        self.redValueLabel.text = 1.0
        
        updateControls()
        
    }
```

2019-01-18 17:31:40.847353-0800 ColorMix[7590:341352] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:890: MGIsDeviceOneOfType is not supported on this platform.
Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 15

Answer (score 0):

Oops. After a few days on this it turns out i did have it correct and it was Xcode that was fouled up. I rest it today and viola, all is good now. Sorry